# How to make the following script as function?

Tags: jquery

I need to make the script into one function

```
var iterations = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
var count = 0;
var button = document.getElementById("click");
var myInterval = setInterval(function test(){ 
if (count >= iterations) {
clearInterval(myInterval);
}else{
count++;
button.click();}
```

I tried but did not work:

```
function test(){
var iterations
....
button.click();}}
```

Comment: Didn't work **how**? (You would need to *call* it, for instance: `test();`)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code,

```
var myInterval = setInterval(test, 0);
function test() {
    var iterations, count;
    ...........do iterations with `count`.....
    if (count >= iterations) {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    } else {
        count++;
        button.click();
    }
}
```